# SQL command mode SQL SERVER - unable to Print

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run these commands and I am getting below result. A single quote ('GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql
) keeps appearing in o/p, now matter what I try. Please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
:setvar ScriptPath 'C:\ProjectWork\DatabaseFiles\DEV\23OctScriptDev\'

:setvar SQLFile 'GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql'


 PRINT $(ScriptPath)'GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql'
 PRINT $(ScriptPath)$(SQLFile)
```

**output:**

C:\ProjectWork\DatabaseFiles\DEV\23OctScriptDev\'GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql
C:\ProjectWork\DatabaseFiles\DEV\23OctScriptDev\'GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql

Answer (score 0):

Please use `+` as concatenation operator like below:

```
PRINT $(ScriptPath)+$(SQLFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the strings using `+`:

```
:setvar ScriptPath 'C:\ProjectWork\DatabaseFiles\DEV\23OctScriptDev\'

:setvar SQLFile 'GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql'

 PRINT $(ScriptPath)+'GetDetailsToSendApprovalMail.sql'
 PRINT $(ScriptPath)+$(SQLFile)
```