# SQL command mode - unable to run command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I just answered this question but never tried to run it. So I tried it..
[SQL command mode SQL SERVER - unable to Print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521410/sql-command-mode-sql-server-unable-to-print/53521635#53521635)

and I thought if Print works then the command will run for sure but to my surprise it didn't

```
    USE [DBName]  
        :setvar ScriptPath 'C:\Work\'
        :setvar SQLFile 'Test.sql'

         ----- commented  PRINT $(ScriptPath) + $(SQLFile)    ---- Works 
        GO
         :r $(ScriptPath) + $(SQLFile)   ---  Doesn't work 
-- throws:A fatal scripting error occurred. Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing :r

             :r $(ScriptPath)+$(SQLFile)   ---  Doesn't work 
    -- throws:A fatal scripting error occurred. Unable to process :r command
             GO
```

I searched but couldn't find correct answer.

What is needed to be fixed here ?

Comment: :setvar only works in SQL command mode. Is it where you are now?

Comment: yes . SQL command mode is ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked.

```
USE [DBName]  
        :setvar ScriptPath "C:\Work\"
        :setvar SQLFile "Test.sql"

        GO
         :r $(ScriptPath)$(SQLFile)
```

Comment: please mark your answer. It will be helpful to others

Comment: I can accept my answer after 24 hrs, so will do tomorrow.